# jquery .filter() function on large array is slow in IE

Tags: jquery, performance, internet-explorer

I have an array of javascript objects containing about 6300 elements.

I am trying to use jQuery to iterate through those elements and create lists of options for several drop-down lists that can be used to filter those 6300 elements.

In Firefox, this works with no problem, but in IE, I get an error about the script running slow.  I've been playing with the code trying to get a set of the data without causing that IE error, but so far, I've had no luck.  Below are the methods I have already tried:

Using "indexOf" to create a distinct list of "Jurisdictions".

```
    var arrayJurisdiction = dataSet.filter(function (item, i, a) {
        return i.Jurisdiction == a.indexOf(item.Jurisdiction);
    });
```

Iterating over each element, checking to see if the value already exists in the secondary array, and if it doesn't, then adding it.

```
    g$.each(dataSet, function (key, value) {
        var matchingJurisdiction = arrayJurisdiction.filter(function (item) {
            return value.Jurisdiction == item;
        })[0];
        if (matchingJurisdiction == null) {
            arrayJurisdiction.push(value.Jurisdiction);
        }
    });
```

Both of these methods result in IE giving me an error about a script running too slowly.  Is there any faster way of doing this?

*EDIT***
Based on feedback below, I have changed the method to use for loops instead of .each() and .filter(), but I am still receiving the "stop this script?" dialog in IE.

Here is the revised code, using the for loops.  Also, I have included all the filters I am attempting to fill (not just the first one).

```
    for (var i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
        var value = dataSet[i];

        var matchingJurisdiction = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayJurisdiction.length; i++) {
            var item = arrayJurisdiction[i];
            if (item == value.Jurisdiction) {
                matchingJurisdiction == item;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchingJurisdiction == null) {
            arrayJurisdiction.push(value.Jurisdiction);
        }



        var valueYear = new Date(value.Treatment_Date).getFullYear();
        var matchingYear = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayYear.length; i++) {
            var item = arrayYear[i];
            if (item == valueYear) {
                matchingYear == item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (matchingYear == null) {
            arrayYear.push(valueYear);
        }
        var matchingProjectClass = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayProjectClass.length; i++) {
            var item = arrayProjectClass[i];
            if (item == valueYear) {
                matchingProjectClass == item;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchingProjectClass == null) {
            arrayProjectClass.push(value.Project_Classification);
        }

        var matchingImprovementType = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < arrayImprovementType.length; i++) {
            var item = arrayImprovementType[i];
            if (item == valueYear) {
                matchingImprovementType == item;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matchingImprovementType == null) {
            arrayImprovementType.push(value.Improvement_Type);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If speed is your goal, then the first thing you should do is switch to a for loop with no function call rather than `.filter()` and `.each()`.

Comment: Is your goal simply to merge two arrays? If that's the case and your arrays are large, you'll find it much faster if you use an object to store the items in the array since `a in obj` will be much faster than  `arr.indexOf(a)` for large arrays. (Where `a` is what you're trying to find, `obj` is an object with the values as keys and `arr` is an array of the objects.)

Comment: If you could describe what data values you have and what you're trying to accomplish folks could probably suggest much better code, perhaps using an object as a lookup table.  But, I can't quite follow what data you have and what you're trying to accomplish from the short pieces of code.  Anything that calls .indexOf repeatedly in a loop should probably be replaced with a lookup on an object, even if it means a preprocess pass to create the object.

Comment: I actually have 4 separate arrays I am creating from different values in the original array. I am creating four different drop downs to filter the original array on, and Jurisdiction is just one of the four.  I am creating the others in the exact same way.  I am going to try removing all .each and .filter methods and replace with for loops first.

Comment: I have updated the question with more data.  Changing to use only for loops and no .each or .filter methods didn't appear to resolve the problem.  But I know for sure that the problem is with this code because when I step-through the code, it is in this section that I get the "Stop this Script?" dialog in IE.  I will say that changing to the for loops did increase performance, just not enough to prevent the problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 Can you elaborate on the idea of using an object as a lookup table?  Perhaps point me to some references that might assist me in trying this out?

Comment: You can find a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121330/slow-executing-js-in-ie-and-ff/10535843#10535843

Answer (score 1):

Dropping jQuery `each()` is certainly an option as it does some funny stuff with the scope beside actual iteration. Another real is that your algorithm seem to be O(n^2) which is pretty bad. I would simply sort your `dataSet` on `Jurisdiction` value, and then loop over keeping previous value and eliminating duplicates. That is going to be the O of the sort algorithm, which is likely using quick sort algorithm O(n*log(n)), but is also likely implemented much more efficiently in native code.

```
dataSet.sort(function(a, b)
{
    if (a.Jurisdiction > b.Jurisdiction)
        return 1;
    if (a.Jurisdiction < b.Jurisdiction)
        return -1;
    return 0;
});

var prev = null;
var filtered = new Array(dataSet.length);
for (var i=0; i<dataSet.length; i++)
{
    if (prev == null || prev.Jurisdiction != dataSet[i].Jusrisdiction)
        filtered.push(dataSet[i]);
    prev = dataSet[i];
}
```