# Slow executing js in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, json, performance

I have this function that runs over returned json data. It is really fast in chrome, but slow in IE and FF. Suggestions on how I might improve this? The data returned is about 15 objects. This creates a bunch of anchors at the top with lists under each heading.

```
function list_response(jsonData) {
    "use strict";
    var lists = document.getElementById("lists"), anchors = document.getElementById("anchors"), jItems = jsonData.items;
    jItems.sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.name.toLowerCase());
            });
    for (var i = 0; i < jItems.length; i++) {
        var pList = jItems[i], str = "", ank = "";
        str += '<span class="backtotop">[ <a href="#">Back to top</a> ]</span><br /><br /><br /><li class="title nodot"><a class="pHeader" name="' + pList.name + '"><h2>' + pList.name + '</h2></a></li>';
        ank += '<a class="pHeader" href="#' + pList.name + '">' + pList.name + '</a>&nbsp; ';
        lists.innerHTML += str;
        anchors.innerHTML += ank;

        for (var j = 0; j < jsonData.items[i]["videos"].length; j++) {
            var vList = jsonData.items[i]["videos"][j];
            var strs = "";
            strs += '<li class="nodot"><a href="https://www.site.org/videos/Video_Player.page?bctid=' + vList.id + '">' + vList.name + '</a></li>';
            lists.innerHTML += strs;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what versions of the browsers are you using? your hardware? there are a lot of factors that can affect this.

Comment: I believe Chrome optimizes `sort()`. How does doing `.toLowerCase()` on all the `jItems` beforehand change things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a version of your code that combines the following performance enhancements:

1. Only add to innerHTML once at the end of the loop.  You want to avoid doing that as often as you can because it causes an entire reparse of all the HTML in that item every time you add onto it.  This minimizes the number of transactions with the DOM which can be the slowest part of the whole routine.  This improved version cuts the number of DOM transactions a lot.  If `jItems.length` was `20` and the average number of videos was 5, this would cut the number of DOM transactions to 1/50th the number of DOM transactions.
2. Accumulate string data into an array with `.push()` and do a `.join()` at the very end rather than adding onto the end of the string every time.  The JS engine can often join lots of strings at once much more efficiently than joining each segment piecemeal.
3. When accumulating string data into arrays, there is no longer a need to initialize the temporaries on each loop or sub-loop.
4. Rather than get `pList` and then have four references to `pList.name`, just get the name value once and use it directly.
5. Cache `jItems[i]` in the loop because it's referenced several places rather than recalculating it every time.
6. Calculate the len variable for each `for` loop just once and compare to that rather than recalculating it on every iteration.
7. Cache `jItems[i]["videos"]` once in the outer loop rather than redoing it every time in the inner loop.
8. If there are a large number of items in `jsonData.items`, then the sort algorithm isn't very efficient since it has to recalculate a lowercase version of each name for every comparison.  You could prebuild all the lowercase versions in one pass (once per item) and then just use them in the sort algorithm rather than have to redo them every time two items are compared.

These changes result in this code:

```
function list_response(jsonData) {
    "use strict";
    var lists = document.getElementById("lists"), anchors = document.getElementById("anchors"), jItems = jsonData.items;
    var results = [], anks = [], vList, pListName, item, videoItem;
    // precache all lower case versions to make sorting faster
    var i, iLen = jItems.length, j, jLen;
    for (var i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
        jItems[i].nameLower = jItems[i].name.toLowerCase();
    }
    jItems.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a.nameLower.localeCompare(b.nameLower);
    });
    for (i = 0; i < iLen; i++) {
        item = jItems[i];                   // cache for use in loops
        videoItem = item["videos"];      // cache for use in loops
        pListName = item.name;            // cache for use in multiple places
        results.push('<span class="backtotop">[ <a href="#">Back to top</a> ]</span><br /><br /><br /><li class="title nodot"><a class="pHeader" name="' + pListName + '"><h2>' + pListName + '</h2></a></li>');
        anks.push('<a class="pHeader" href="#' + pListName + '">' + pListName + '</a>&nbsp; ');

        for (j = 0, jLen = videoItem.length; j < jLen; j++) {
            vList = videoItem[j];
            results.push('<li class="nodot"><a href="https://www.site.org/videos/Video_Player.page?bctid=' + vList.id + '">' + vList.name + '</a></li>');
        }
    }
    lists.innerHTML += results.join("");
    anchors.innerHTML += anks.join("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. It was very helpful to complete my understanding.

Comment: I an getting commas after each item. Is this from the push or join? How do I remove those?

Comment: @MrBrimm - It's from the `.join()`.  Change them both to `.join("")`.  I didn't realize join defaults to a comma if you don't specifically set it to an empty string.

Comment: Ah that's it! I did some searching and couldn't figure out why it was adding that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can try length cacheing - create a variable `l = jItems.length`, for example, and use that in the `for` loop's condition rather than getting the `length` property every time - depending on the implementation, there is usually an overhead with looking up an array's length, so if you have a big array this difference can be noticeable.

Also, create temporary variables to keep your `str` and `ank` strings as they get bigger, then only put them in the `innerHTML` right at the end.

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially the answer for me on what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't be using strings and innerHTML to construct your HTML. You should use the DOM.

Comment: Often times using innerHTML is significantly faster than DOM building.  Furthermore, using client-side templates can make your code much easier to follow and maintain for complex layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Old trick and not so sure if it's relevant anymore but

```
var builder = [];
builder.push('foo');
builder.push('bar');
builder.push('baz');
var str = builder.join('')
```

used to be a lot faster in IE than

```
var str = '';
str += 'foo';
str += 'bar';
str += 'baz';
```

Comment: At least in IE9, this is no longer the case. See innerHTML1 and innerHTML2 benchmarks [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
var strHTML = "";
var ankHTML = "";

for (var i=0; i < jItems.length; i++){
  ...    
  strHTML += str;
  ankHTML += ank;
  ...
}
lists.innerHTML = strHTML ;
anchors.innerHTML = ankHTML ;
```

Comment: Minimize the number of transactions with DOM.

Answer (score 0):

The primary performance bottleneck here is undoubtedly the way you are working with innerHTML.

`el.innerHTML += aString;` is of course equivalent to `el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML + aString;`.

This means that for each call the DOM will be serialized to a string of HTML, and then deserialized back into a valid DOM.  This is a lot of unnecessary work.

Instead, either:

(a) Build all the HTML up front and assign innerHTML just once per element.

(b) Append elements or document fragments to the parent node.