# Replacing DOM element slow in IE compared to FV or GoogleChrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, replacewith

The application I am working needs fast response. The client is supposed to create a configuration by completing a form. Each modification on the form sends the form to the sever for validation. The server responds with a new HTML page.The page is then rendered in the browser.  My task is to add Ajax to this process so that the user experience is improved. Here's what I've done so far :

```
function doSubmitWithAjax(){
  var datum = $('#hiddenvars').serialize();
  var ajax=$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'frontend',
    cache : false,
    dataType : 'html', 
    data : datum 
  });
  ajax.success(function(XHR,text,jqXHR){
    var dom = document.createElement('div');
    dom.innerHTML=XHR;
    var bod = $('#hiddenvars',dom);
    $('#hiddenvars').replaceWith(bod);
  });
  ajax.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert('request error '+errorThrown);
  });
 }
```

XHR is the HTML page that is received from the server. Basically I just want to retrieve the form (#hiddenvars) and place it instead of the form already existent in the DOM.

The function `doSubmitWithAjax()` is fired every time a change has occurred in the form. The present implementation works fine for Firefox and Chrome. With IE the response time is too high. I have used some tools to inspect what takes that much time and it turned out that `replaceWith()` is slow (1.3 seconds) compared to FF(0.2 seconds).

My question : How can I improve the response time for IE? What can I use instead of replaceWith() ? I have tried :  `$('#hiddenvars').empty().replaceWith(bod);` because I don't need the replaced form from the DOM, but still slow.

Thanks!

Comment: Congratulations, you've discovered that IE is much slower than its more modern brethren.

Comment: 1) Cheat: cache request, so if a request use data:1, and the next is data:1, take the result directly from a cache in the js, not from the server.
2) .... 2? ... you are already doing the basic things to make stuff fast. Avoiding building things with dom,  using replace/clone.   I can't see why IE don't like your code.
Perhaps is that  var bod = $('#hiddenvars',dom);  $('#hiddenvars').replaceWith(bod);, there as to be a simpler way to do the same thing, that don't make IE angry.

Comment: There is no reason to send the whole form to the server for each little form change. IE might be slow but your design is flawed.

Comment: @ ZippyV: the form is sent to the server because all the fields are adjusted according to the current input modification. If there are 100 fields and the user modifies the 53rd then maybe another 20 fields are modified according to the selection on the 53rd. This is the logic behind it and it's all legacy code..I can't really do much about it.

Comment: Can you simplify the HTML? Remove inline styles, repeating classes and change the css file?

Comment: You can find a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121330/slow-executing-js-in-ie-and-ff/10535843#10535843

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that:

```
var bod = $('#hiddenvars',dom);
$('#hiddenvars').replaceWith(bod);
```

Replaces *hiddenvars* with itself. See if something like the following faster:

```
var x = document.getElementById('hiddenvars');
var p = x.parentNode;
p.innerHTML = '';
p.appendChild(x);
p.appendChild(bod);
```

You might also want to retain a reference to *bod* so you just replace its content each time rather than removing and inserting *hiddenvars* each time.

#### Edit

Unfortunately you can't use *getElementById* on an element, you'll need to sift through the content of *dom* to find it. Using `dom.getElementsByTagName('form')` will at least mean you only have to sift through the forms, e.g.

```
var form, forms = bod.getElementsByTagName('form');
var i = forms.length;
while (i-- && !form ) { 
  if (forms[i].id == 'hiddenvars') form = forms[i];
}

if (form) {
  var x = document.getElementById('hiddenvars');
  x.parentNode.replaceChild(form, x);
}
```

Comment: `var bod = $('#hiddenvars',dom);` gets the form from the `dom` object which wraps the `XHR` received from the server. `$('#hiddenvars').replaceWith(bod);` takes my current form and replaces it with `bod` (the updated form received from the server). Anyway your suggestion seems valid since it doesn't use `replaceWith()` which basically is the bottleneck (according to dynaTrace).I'll give it a try.Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again! It's actually faster.