# Slow Isotope animation in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm using Isotope and have an issue in Internet Explorer. While in Chrome/Firefox, the animation completes within one second. IE 7-9 takes five seconds.

Transitions are being used, and the CSS is the same as listed at http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/animating.html#css_transitions

The JS that loads the script:

```
$('#timeline').isotope({
    itemSelector : '.item',
    transformsEnabled: true,
    layoutMode: 'spineAlign',
    spineAlign:{
        gutterWidth: 56
    },
    getSortData: {
        timestamp: function($elem){
            return parseFloat($elem.find('.timestamp').text());
        }
    },
    sortBy: 'timestamp',
    sortAscending: false,
    itemPositionDataEnabled: true
});
```

Anyone know why IE is so slow?

One thing I forgot to mention (kinda important) is that I have a couple of sort buttons that do 2 things:

1. Adjust the 'timestamp' of some items
2. Resort the items

   ```
   $('#timeline').isotope('reloadItems').isotope({sortAscending: false});
   ```

It is this process that is slow in IE. Not the initial page load.

Comment: I don't see any difference in my recreation of your issue (http://texas-asl.com/x.htm - hit refresh). Transition times look the same in IE and Chrome.

Comment: I updated my original question to include a critical piece of information that I forgot to include.

Comment: You can find a solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121330/slow-executing-js-in-ie-and-ff/10535843#10535843

Answer (score 0):

Because Chrome and Firefox support css transitions and offload the work to the GPU.
IE up to 9 does not. This means all the 'transitions' are calculated in Javascript which is a lot more costly in performance.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions